# Should copy constructor be private or public

Tags: c++, private, copy-constructor, public

I am writing an abstract class that will be a parent for several other classes. I am thinking the copy constructor should be made private because you are using an abstract class and there is nothing to copy.  However, I am not a 100% sure.

Am I correct and if I am not why should it be public or protected?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The copy constructor should be private if you do not want objects of the class to be copied. Otherwise, it should be public.

Comment: It is impossible for the base class constructor to make a copy of a derived class, so I don't understand when it would make sense for it to be public.

Comment: @MarkRansom I meant something like [this](http://ideone.com/n2ndl), but people could still implement copy constructor in the derived class.

Comment: Thanks I thought so. A follow up question, because it is private and will never be used, no code needs to be in the copy constructor because it will never be used.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Aaron It shouldn't be used, therefore there are no needs to implement it. If you try to use it, you'll get a compilation error anyway.

Comment: @Aaron, if the copy constructor had code in it what would it do? If your abstract base class has data members it might have to initialize them, in which case the constructor should be protected and be called by all the derived class copy constructors. That's not generally the case though.

Answer (score 8):

I think `protected` is the best choice: it leaves the decision on whether or not the object is copyable to the derived classes, while prohibiting the copying at the abstract class level, preventing the dreaded [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Comment: I think the difference between protected and private is moot in this case, since the base class copy constructor will be empty and won't need to be called.

Comment: @MarkRansom I think it is a good idea to call the copy constructor of the base class even if you know for sure that it is currently empty. The compiler will optimize it out as long as the copy constructor in the base class stays empty, but if someone refactors the base to include a non-empty copy constructor, the derived classes would not need to change.

Comment: Very good point. I've edited my own answer to include that possibility.

Answer (score 3):

By making the copy constructor private you'll help prevent inadvertent object slicing, where you make a copy of a derived class but lose all the properties of that derived class. The derived classes can make their own copy constructors that are public and do the right thing.

There's one case where the copy constructor should be protected instead of private, when the abstract class has data members. This doesn't happen very often. The base class can copy the base class members while the derived class copies its own members.

```
class AbstractBase
{
public:
    AbstractBase(const std::string &init) : wtf(init) {}
    virtual ~AbstractBase() {}
    void DoSomething() = 0;
protected:
    AbstractBase(const AbstractBase &r) : wtf(r.wtf) {}

    const std::string wtf;
};

class Derived : public AbstractBase
{
public:
    // ...
    Derived(const Derived &r) : AbstractBase(r), moredata(r.moredata) {}
private:
    int moredata;
};
```

Comment: You're right! I thought the base class copy constructor was called by default. Apparently you have to explicitly call it. What a mistake!

Comment: Isn't slicing prevented by the base class being abstract?

Comment: @FredLarson, facepalm! Of course you can't instantiate an abstract class.